# Convert string format to another date format

Tags: blackberry, java-me, time

My string format is: M/d/yyyy h:m:s aa

Now, I want to change it in yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss format.

How can I change it in this format. Please tell me appropriate solution

Comment: You will have to parse the *source* date by yourself (with the help of `HttpDateParser`) construct a `Calendar` object from the parsed date and then pass it to `SimpleDateFormat.format()` method to reformat it according to your needs.

Comment: Actually, in your case, it may be easier to reformat it directly (with string manipulation methods).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `getConvertedDate(String)`, will do a plain text parsing for conversion.

```
private String getConvertedDate(String inputDate) {
    // extract and adjust Month
    int index = inputDate.indexOf('/');
    String month = inputDate.substring(0, index);
    if (month.length() < 2) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }

    // extract and adjust Day
    inputDate = inputDate.substring(index + 1);
    index = inputDate.indexOf('/');
    String day = inputDate.substring(0, index);
    if (day.length() < 2) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }

    // extract Year
    inputDate = inputDate.substring(index + 1);
    index = inputDate.indexOf(' ');
    String year = inputDate.substring(0, index);

    // extract Hour
    inputDate = inputDate.substring(index + 1);
    index = inputDate.indexOf(':');
    String hour = inputDate.substring(0, index);

    // extract and adjust Minute
    inputDate = inputDate.substring(index + 1);
    index = inputDate.indexOf(':');
    String minute = inputDate.substring(0, index);
    if (minute.length() < 2) {
        minute = "0" + minute;
    }

    // extract and adjust Second
    inputDate = inputDate.substring(index + 1);
    index = inputDate.indexOf(' ');
    String second = inputDate.substring(0, index);
    if (second.length() < 2) {
        second = "0" + second;
    }

    // extract AM/PM marker
    // adjust hour, +12 for PM
    inputDate = inputDate.substring(index + 1);         
    String am_pm_marker = inputDate.substring(0);
    if (am_pm_marker.equalsIgnoreCase("pm")) {
        int hourValue = 0;
        try {
            hourValue = Integer.parseInt(hour);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        hourValue += 12;
        hour = "" + hourValue;
        if (hour.length() < 2) {
            hour = "0" + hour;
        }
    } else {
        if (hour.length() < 2) {
            hour = "0" + hour;
        }
    }

    String outputDate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
    outputDate += "T" + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
    return outputDate;
}
```

Sample input and output:

```
String input = "04/01/2012 9:55:47 pm"; 
System.out.println("Output: " + getConvertedDate(input));
// Output: 2012-04-01T21:55:47
```

Comment: I have already used the same method.
Anyways thanks for your reply.

Answer (score -2):

```
Date date = (Date)new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy h:m:s aa").parse(your_string_date);
String finalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss").format(date)
```

Basically the first SimpleDateFormat recognizes your original format and parses it into a Date. Then the second one formats the date object to what you need.

I don't have jdk around to test here, but it should work.

Check this links for format syntax in case something doesn't work:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: API docs you refer to, are for Java SE while question is about **Java ME** which may not have `SimpleDateFormat` (J2ME CLDC 1.0 and 1.1 certainly hasn't)

Comment: "SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy h:m:s aa").parse()"

"parse" method is not available for SimpleDateFormat Class.

Comment: @AnkitRox, You can check the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892156/blackberry-how-to-convert-time-from-string-in-hhhhmmss-ss-to-mmss-format. I think `M/d/yyyy h:m:s aa` isn't an usual pattern for using HttpDateParser, http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/http/HttpDateParser.html.

Comment: yes, it is not a valid pattern but I am getting it from webservices. So tell me solution for such condition.

Comment: You can just parse the String. Then it is possible to convert it to `Date` object and finally convert it to desired format.